# High, strange and varied pings to different dedicated gaming servers

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet

I have been troubleshooting my network for months and I am completely lost and my ISP's employees can't help me properly and I am stuck with them as there have been no gateways dedicated to other ISPs for years in my little town.

Here are the issues:

1. Frequent DSL link down causing frequent connection loss to the internet.
2. High and varied ping times to different dedicated gaming servers.

In order to troubleshoot that, I used Ping Plotter and the DSL log from my modem/router and I found the following:

1. Very high and varied latency (24-800 ms, average 81 ms) from modem IP 192.168.2.1 to gateway IP 188.247.31.33 in the first hop in the traceroute.
2. Lower and more stable ping time (24-60 ms, average 30 ms) to the second hop to another unknown IP for me: 188.247.31.40.
3. Equal or slightly different latency to my ISP server 10.x.x.x.
4. Another latency jump (63-120 ms) to a set of x.x.x.x servers reaching target at 100, 80, 70, or 120 ms depending on the time during the day the target server has varied latency so nothing is stable.

Now for the DSL log:

1. SNR margin is usually 30-39/25-30 down/up dB and suddenly it hits low values when the DSL link goes down and the connection to the internet is lost.
2. Line Attenuation is usually 25-13/20-10 dB down/up being very stable and does not change.
3. Sudden CRC error detection from 1 to 900 for downstream and something similar to upstream when the DSL connection is lost.

I contacted my ISP thousands of times and every time they try to give me a static DNS things became even worse. I also contacted my local service to check the phone line and they don't come to see and check it, replying that "as long as you can use your phone we can't help you so contact us when you have your line cut only..." so I have to do that myself as I live in a wasteland.

I would be very happy with stable 80 ms latency in online games but not as high to hell with frequent connection loss.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: How far do you live from your phone exchange? This could just be a case of you just living in a rural area.

Comment: "I am stuck with them as there has been no gateways for years in my little town."  - Try the same thing at a friend's home

Comment: Please run http://dslreports.com/speedtest from a desktop/laptop web browser and edit your question to provide a link to the results page or at least report your bufferbloat grade.

Comment: Bufferbloat is terrible, but it is not an issue to me because this is a dedicated line just for gaming which means no other traffic are involved to cause a bufferbloat.